# Web SQL INSERT INTO causing a crash

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, web-sql

I have created a database, a table, and pre-populated it with initial values in one method:

```
function Setup(cb)
{
    _db = openDatabase("MoneyMan", "1.0", "Money Manager", 8 * 1024 * 1024);

    // Wallets
    _db.transaction(function(tx) {

        // Create wallet table
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE Wallets (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, balance FLOAT, target FLOAT, transactions INTEGER)', [],
            function(tx, res) {

                // Add initial wallets
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Wallets (name, balance, target, transactions) VALUES ("Main", 0, 0, NULL)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Wallets (name, balance, target, transactions) VALUES ("Bills", 0, 0, NULL)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Wallets (name, balance, target, transactions) VALUES ("Savings", 0, 0, NULL)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Wallets (name, balance, target, transactions) VALUES ("Business", 0, 0, NULL)');

            });


        cb();
    });
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

I have a button to add a new wallet to the table, and it doesn't work. Even this code breaks:

```
_db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Wallets VALUES (NULL, "Testing", 0, 0, NULL)');
});
```

EDIT: I have also tried listing the fields as such:

```
_db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Wallets (name, balance, target, transactions) VALUES (?, 0, 0, NULL)', [name]);
    });
```

On Chrome, the whole page breaks and I get "Aww, Snap". On Android nothing happens at all. However, when I refresh the page, it seems the wallet was successfully added.

I've searched all over the internet for a solution to this and it's driving me mad. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

When I set a breakpoint on executeSQL(), it runs fine. It's only when it tries to leave the transaction callback that it breaks.

**EDIT:**

I should note that this is Javascript compiled from another language. The variable "_db" is accessible from the second method. There are no issues if I do a SELECT statement when I try to add a new wallet. Only INSERT INTO breaks.

Comment: just a thought, might work, try putting the _db.transaction(...); inside a function and assign it to the onclick() of that button. Because you said item was successfully added after the crash, there seems to be no error with the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

try

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Wallets (name, balance, target, transactions) VALUES ("Testing", 0, 0, NULL)');
```

you are passing NULL as a primary key which is already on auto-increment

Comment: I have tried this too. This is the original code:

    _db.transaction(function(tx) {
   

   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Wallets (name, balance, target, transactions) VALUES (?, 0, 0, NULL)', [name],
    function(tx, res) {
     cb(res);
    }
   );

  });

Comment: just check the parameters you are passing. 
you are passing 5 parameters (NULL, "Testing", 0, 0, NULL)
whereas the scheme has only 4

Comment: do you have any stack trace of Exception info ?

Comment: and are you sure you can use a "prepared statement" rather than a solid SQL query ? try using a definite SQL query without "?" (prepared statement)

Comment: Stack trace just says anonymous function. My original code uses a prepared statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114366/discussion-between-rejo-chandran-and-zotoaster).

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting the correct number of values.  You want to provide a field list as you do in your first inserts.  `(name, balance, target, transactions) VALUES`